# Fluent animation in Swing

Tags: java, swing, animation

I'd like to create a fluent 60fps animation. The animation itself seems to be approximately at 10fps, even though my render thread calls the run method 60 times a second. I'm pretty sure the problem is that the Swing was not created with animations in mind. So what is the easiest way to solve this? Thanks a lot

Code:

```
import aurelienribon.tweenengine.Tween;
import aurelienribon.tweenengine.TweenManager;
import object.Text;
import java.awt.*;

public class Main implements RenderThread.RunnerIface {

    private final Frame mFrame;
    private RenderThread mRenderThread;
    private TweenManager mTweenManager;

    private Text mText = new Text("text", 250, 250);

    public Main() {
        mFrame = new Frame();
        mRenderThread = new RenderThread(this);
        mTweenManager = new TweenManager();
        Tween.registerAccessor(Text.class, new TextAccessor());
        new Thread(mRenderThread).start();

        this.animateRight();
    }

    private void animateLeft() {
        Tween.to(mText, -1, 1000.0f)
                .target(100, 250)
                .start(mTweenManager);
    }

    private void animateRight() {
        Tween.to(mText, -1, 10000.0f)
                .target(400, 250)
                .start(mTweenManager);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    @Override
    public void run(float delta) {
        mTweenManager.update(delta);
        System.out.format("Delta: %f, FPS: %f\n", delta, 1000/delta);

        Graphics g = mFrame.getCanvas().getGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, mFrame.getCanvas().getWidth(), mFrame.getCanvas().getHeight());

        mText.render(g);
    }
}
```

Edit:

Second attempt:

```
public class DrawPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    private Timer tm = new Timer(30, this);
    JLabel label = new JLabel("Here is my label");
    private int x = 0, velX = 2;
    private long time;

    public DrawPanel() {
        super();
//        this.setLayout(null);
        this.x = this.getWidth();
        this.label.setBounds(x,100,100,100);
        this.add(label);

    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        super.paintComponent(g);

/*        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());*/

//        x=this.getWidth();
        time = System.currentTimeMillis();

        tm.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
//        x+=1;
        int l = (int) ((System.currentTimeMillis() - time)*0.1);
        this.time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println(l);

        x=x+l;
        this.label.setBounds(x,100,100,100);

        this.repaint();
    }
}

public class Main {

    private Frame mFrame;
    private DrawPanel drawPanel;

    public Main() {
        mFrame = new Frame();
        drawPanel = new DrawPanel();
        mFrame.add(drawPanel);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }
}
```

So I completely rewrote my code following MadProgrammer's advices. Now I use swing timer instead of my render thread. Result is still the same, the animation is dropping frames and it's unusable. I'm confident that the actionPerformed method is called as frequently as it should be. I guess the problem is somehow hidden in the repaint method. I tried to call the repaint method on the JFrame but it didn't help.
I was following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I3usNR8JrEE%20tutorial), but everythink seems to work fine in the creator's case.
Thanks

Comment: Don't use getGraphics, this is not how custom painting is done. Swing uses a passive rendering engine, meaning that the repaint manager is making decisions about what and when something should be painted and may actually collapse multiple paint request down into a smaller number of events. It also means that painting may occur at any time, without your knowledge or interaction. You're current code is outside of the prescribed paint process, me sing it won't know when Swing injects its own paint request and could lead to flickering as you fight the paint system

Comment: You should be overriding paintComponent of a Swing based component (like JPanel) and after calling super.paintComponent, perform your custom painting operations every time it's called. When your run method is called, you need to calculate the required state changes for the component, calling appropriate setters to tell the component what's new state is, and call repaint upon it

Comment: If you need absolute control over the paint process, then you should be using a BufferStrategy, but this introduces a new level of complexities and means you can't use Swing components, as the painting process isn't compatible

Comment: Remember, animation is the illusion of change over time, not many people will see the difference between 60fps and 30fps over a small period of time, this means, rather then been focused on a absolute change (the object must 100 pixels regardless of how long it will take), you should be focused on moving the object 100 pixels over a prescribed amount of time, this will help in promoting the illusion ;)

Comment: Although I don't see any flickering with the latest code that you posted: You should not use an AWT `Frame`, but a Swing `JFrame`. Don't start the timer in the `paintComponent` method. The timer should be started *once* (in doubt: In the constructor). You might also consider using `System.nanoTime` instead of `System.currentTimeMillis`, as `nanoTime` has nanosecond resolution. Divide the time difference by `10e9` to convert it to seconds. You should also store the `x` coordinate as a `double`, and only cast it as late as possible: `label.setBounds((int)x, ...)`.

Comment: I updated the code according to Marco13's advice. I tried to run the code on Windows and it seems to run well, however the animation is nowhere close to fluent on my main system on Ubuntu 15.04. :( It's weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the performance problems with Swing I decided to use JavaFX instead. Since I've created quite a lot of code in Swing I didn't want to toss it all away. Fortunately there is JFXPanel for that.
Here is the code with animation example:

```
public class AnimationPanel extends JFXPanel {

    private Text[] nodes = new Text[1];

    public AnimationPanel() {
        super();

        Text t = new Text(10,50, "This is test");
        t.setFill(Color.RED);
        nodes[0] = t;

        final Scene scene = new Scene(new Group(nodes), 800, 600, Color.BLACK);

        this.setScene(scene);

        new AnimationTimer() {
            public int x = 0;
            @Override
            public void handle(long now) {
                for (int i=0; i<1; i++) {
                    final Node node = nodes[i];
                    node.setTranslateX(x);
                    x++;
                }
            }
        }.start();

    }
}
```

You can use this panel as a regular Swing panel.